# REST interface and KIE-WB

Tags: jbpm, kie-wb

I'm trying to exploit **REST API** in order to manage a business process within **KIE-WB**.

For example, I used the business process **Evaluation** which is available in KIE-WB.
I'd like to start a process,

---> So I should use **[POST]** and the URL  **.../jbpmconsole/rest/runtime/org.jbpm:Evaluation:1.0/process/evaluation/start**

I'm asking how obtain the **REST interface** ?, it's possible working with poster of firefox ?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should be able to use the REST interface with any rest client. Look at the documentation to see what are the exposed methods: http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.1/userguide/jBPMRemoteAPI.html#d0e10686

HTH

Comment: Thanks Sir,It was solved, I used "Advanced REST Client Application" available in "Chrome Web Store".

Comment: Now, I encounter a problem when I try "http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/task/548/exit".                                       The Status was :401 Unauthorized.                                    The Error was :<error>User '[UserImpl:'salaboy']' does not have permissions to execution operation 'Exit' on task id 548</error>                             Could you please help me. Thanks.